# Write conflict when updating main form from pop-up

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a 'keyboard' created in Access used to input data in the main form using Google Remote Desktop from an Android phone (most input will be done locally using a computer and normal keyboard).

Main form based on multi-table query contains data. Remote (Android) user clicks on a form field and keyboard pops-up where the user selects the letters with a mouse pointer and eventually clicks an OK button which overwrites the original field data of the main form with the selected letters.

So far so good however on leaving the main form the Write Conflict MessageBox appears and all of the newly edited data from the 'keyboard' disappears - the original data reappears, in other words nothing changes.

The code for the OK button on the pop-up keyboard is:

```vb
Private Sub tOK_Click()

    Dim p As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim txtResult As String
    Dim pFrmName As String
    Dim frmName As String
    Dim ctrl As String

    'On Error GoTo errHandler
    pFrmName = Me.pFrmName  ' the first three or the lasr three strings can be dropped as they contain the same data
    frmName = Me.frmName
    ctrl = Me.ctrlName
    p = pFrmName
    f = frmName
    c = ctrl

    If p = c Then
        Forms(f).SetFocus
        Forms(f)(c).Value = Me.txtResult
    Else
        Forms(f)(p)(c).SetFocus
        Forms(f)(p)(c).Value = Me.txtResult
    End If
```

I have a function called vkbddata which I put in the main form's textBox's OnClick event.

How do I enter the data remotely avoiding the Write Conflict?

********************************************************* 08 Sept 2018
functions:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function vkbdData()
'used to provide data to virtual keyboard so it can assign new data to underlying form
On Error GoTo err_handler

If Forms!f00_logon!vkbd = True Then 'if user checks virtual keyboard

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim ctrlName As String
Dim pFrmName As String ' parent form if one exists
Dim frmName As String
Dim ctrlcaption As String
Dim sValue As String

If IsNull(Screen.ActiveForm.Controls.Parent) Then
frmName = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name
Else
frmName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
End If
pFrmName = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name

ctrlcaption = ""

ctrlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
    If IsNull(Screen.ActiveControl.Value) Then
    sValue = ""
    Else
    sValue = Screen.ActiveControl.Value
    End If
'Debug.Print ctrlName

vkbdData = keyBoardPopUp(frmName, pFrmName, ctrlName, ctrlcaption, sValue)

End If

Exit_Form:
 Exit Function

err_handler:
 MsgBox Err.Description
 Resume Exit_Form


End Function

Public Function keyBoardPopUp(pFrmName, frmName, ctrlName, ctrlcaption, sValue) As String
Dim frm As Object
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim sParameters As String

'strange deliminators (>,|, ...) to make it easy to tell what each parameter value is
sParameters = pFrmName & ">" & frmName & "|" & ctrlName & "^" & ctrlcaption & "~" & sValue
'Debug.Print "SParameters  " & sParameters
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_keyboard", , , , , , sParameters


End Function
```

---

[image: Write Conflict Error]

Comment: Show the function `vkbddata. Why don't you just pass the reference of the clicked control to the keyboard. Save before error (`form.Dirty = False`).  Error is " Another user has changed your data"?

Comment: Nice question. But please show the exact error message (at least the error code), because your "Write Conflict" can have several meanings in Access. You should also show your vkbddata  function

Comment: ComputerVersteher and Thomas G,

Comment: I have tried screen.deactivated, textBox.deactivated, textBox lost focus, and if me.dirty=true then me.dirty=false.  By the Write Conflict error it's clear Access is aware of the change in the main form.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the built-in virtual keyboard? You can make your code much shorter if you pass the controls reference with vkbdata. It contains all you need (e.g the Form is `Control.Parent`) and  you should use  `Enter` event as you can enter a control without a click.

Comment: ComputerVersteher, i tried the Windows built-in keyboard but it covers half of the screen and i don't see a way of changing its size (although it can be moved) so users can see my program not only that it also won't save changes (my original problem).  Not sure what you mean by 'the Form is Control.Parent and use the Enter Event'.

Comment: I have another two forms where the keyboard works without any error but they are simple forms whereas my Main form is built on a query based on two tables one of which are from QuickBooks.  I think the multi-table query is causing the problem and the virtual keyboard is working properly. The error code is "2766 - the object doesn't contain the automation object "|""  This used to work but I replaced a sub-form with fields from the second table.

Sorry I asked the wrong question.  I think the answer is to re-create the sub-form.  Thanks for your time.